# Delete specified duplicate rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, duplicates, delete-row, sql-delete

Consider the situation below:

```
CREATE TABLE PostTags
    (
     userid int DEFAULT NULL,
     tstamp int DEFAULT NULL,
      feed varchar(4)
    );

INSERT INTO PostTags VALUES (1,1, "edi");
INSERT INTO PostTags VALUES (1,2, "np");
INSERT INTO PostTags VALUES (1,1, "oth");
INSERT INTO PostTags VALUES (3,4, "pq");
INSERT INTO PostTags VALUES (1,2, "di");
```

'Timestamp' and 'userid' in my original problem have real datatypes, but I am simplifying the problem here for easy understanding.

It is known that for a given timestamp, a user can only perform one type of feed. If I know that I want to keep feeds of a particular type say "edi" and get rid of feeds of other type like "oth" (in this case, "oth" is the second value for userid 1 and timestamp 1) what type of query can I write?

I tried to give alter ignore to see what it would delete and what it would keep, but it gave me an error:

```
alter ignore table PostTags add unique index ix_mm (userid, tstamp);
```

Error:
Schema Creation Failed: Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'ix_mm':

Any suggestions on how I can proceed are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Your alter table statement uses columns not in the table.

Comment: @Gordon corrected my alter ignore command

Comment: . . Do you consider this a duplicate?

Comment: yes, i do. The link @Marc B pointed out seems to provide a solution. Thanks though!